# Wordpress Cron: Running as which user?

Tags: cron, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin. It has some job to be execute by wp_cron. Now within the script, it create/edit some posts automatically. So which user will be running the cron job?

Also I notice it failed when calling `WP_Filesystem()`

Comment: don't know for shure but i gues it's the admin user, you can have a small test and see what happens, allso you don't realy need to worry much about it as you can change the user id when you save the post ...

Answer (score 6):

Well I've found out that it's running as no one, as `get_current_user_id()` returns 0

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some debugging today and I've found that `get_current_user_id()` is often, but not always, `0` (logged out). The cron can get triggered by *any* user and your code should anticipate that.